# How to design UI for multiple selection in a drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm setting up a UI for my application. I would like to have some idea about your guy's experiences. 
I need to have multiple selections from different sources.

Input (Sources): Companies, Department. Multiple companies, departments allowed.

Output: People who belong to selected items

For example, I can select company1, company2, and select department1, department2 from a dropdown list.

I select one by one property( Select company1, company2, then go to another dropdown to select department1,2...)

In the end, I have company1,2,3 checked, department 1,2,3 checked.

Then the result will tell me user1...n belong to the selected list above.

The problem is nothing if I have only a few company and department but if coming to be complicated if I have multiple (more than 6 companies and departments). I can't come up with any good UI design for this problem.

I expected the output of (selected(checked company1,2,3... + department1,2,3)) -> result person1,2,3 belong to checked items.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Select Company: </p>
        <select name="companySelector" multiple>

        </select>
        <p>Select Department: </p>
        <select name="departmentSelector" multiple>

        </select>
        <p>Persons: </p>
        <ul id="persons">

        </ul>
        <script>
            var companySelector = document.querySelector("[name='companySelector']");
            var departmentSelector = document.querySelector("[name='departmentSelector']");
            var persons = document.getElementById("persons");
            var temp, temp2 = 0;
            var database = {
                company_1: {
                    c1_department1: ["c1d1person1", "c1d1person2", "c1d1person3", "c1d1person4"],
                    c1_department2: ["c1d2person1", "c1d2person2", "c1d2person3", "c1d2person4"],
                    c1_department3: ["c1d3person1", "c1d3person2", "c1d3person3", "c1d3person4"]
                },
                company_2: {
                    c2_department1: ["c2d1person1", "c2d1person2", "c2d1person3", "c2d1person4"],
                    c2_department2: ["c2d2person1", "c2d2person2", "c2d2person3", "c2d2person4"],
                    c2_department3: ["c2d3person1", "c2d3person2", "c2d3person3", "c2d3person4"]
                },
                company_3: {
                    c3_department1: ["c3d1person1", "c3d1person2", "c3d1person3", "c3d1person4"],
                    c3_department2: ["c3d2person1", "c3d2person2", "c3d2person3", "c3d2person4"],
                    c3_department3: ["c3d3person1", "c3d3person2", "c3d3person3", "c3d3person4"]
                },
                company_4: {
                    c4_department1: ["c4d1person1", "c4d1person2", "c4d1person3", "c4d1person4"],
                    c4_department2: ["c4d2person1", "c4d2person2", "c4d2person3", "c4d2person4"],
                    c4_department3: ["c4d3person1", "c4d3person2", "c4d3person3", "c4d3person4"]
                },
                company_5: {
                    c5_department1: ["c5d1person1", "c5d1person2", "c5d1person3", "c5d1person4"],
                    c5_department2: ["c5d2person1", "c5d2person2", "c5d2person3", "c5d2person4"],
                    c5_department3: ["c5d3person1", "c5d3person2", "c5d3person3", "c5d3person4"]
                }
            }
            for (temp in database) {
                companySelector.innerHTML += '<option value="' + temp + '">' + temp.replace(/_/g, " ") + '</option>';
            }
            companySelector.onchange = function() {
                departmentSelector.innerHTML = "";
                var selectedCompnies = document.querySelectorAll("[name='companySelector'] option:checked");
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedCompnies.length; i++) {
                    for (temp2 in database[selectedCompnies[i].value]) {
                        departmentSelector.innerHTML += '<option value="' + temp2 + '" data-company="' + selectedCompnies[i].value + '">' + temp2.replace(/_/g, " ") + '</option>'
                    }
                }
            }
            departmentSelector.onchange = function() {
                persons.innerHTML = "";
                var selectedDepartments = document.querySelectorAll("[name='departmentSelector'] option:checked");
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedDepartments.length; i++) {
                    var temp3 = selectedDepartments[i].dataset.company;
                    var prsonsArray = database[temp3][selectedDepartments[i].value];
                    for (var x = 0; x < prsonsArray.length; x++) {
                        persons.innerHTML += "<li>" + prsonsArray[x] + "</li>";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/swmz4j3q)

Comment: Thanks, also how can I map the output to JSON obj?

Comment: output is mentioned in an array object named prsonsArray. You can use it...